# SQL Group By - Get unique key of every type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

I have a problem with this SQL Grouping.

If i have a table with 3 columns.  Key is a unique key for every record.  Type is the type of record and Version is the version of the type.

```
ID    Type      Version
------------------------
1      A          200
2      A          100
3      B          200
4      B          200
5      B          100
```

I need to get 1 row for each version of each type

so it would look something like

```
ID    Type       Version
------------------------
1      A           200
2      A           100
3      B           200
5      B           100
```

I know I need to group by the Type and version but I cant seem to figure out how to get the unique key for each Type and Version since they are on the same table

```
SELECT Type, Version FROM TableName GROUP BY Type, Version
```

Gets me all the unique Types and Versions, but I cant figure out how to finish off the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you mean the unique ID?
you need to use an aggregation function like `MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG`

you cant get an unique value. Think about it, if you have:

```
1   A   100
2   A   100
3   A   100
```

you want only one row with

> A   100

but whats the logic to define the ID between 1,2 and 3? It isnt unique. That's why you need a `MAX` or `MIN` or any other aggregation function

Comment: You can select the min(Id) just like I stated.

Comment: yes but it will need the group. I think he wants the "unique" ID on each group of Type, Version.

Comment: I think he wants the min(ID) for each group of Type, Version.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  Thank you for explaining how I need to aggregate on the unique key, because you are right, there is no way to distinguish between 1, 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1):

how about you concatenate the 2 columns and then use it as a GROUP BY parameter

```
SELECT ID, Type, Version, (Type + Version) FROM TableName GROUP BY (Type + Version)
```

Comment: this will gibe error because ID, Type and Version are not in the Group by part.

Comment: ok then you can fix the error by using aggregate functions like `SELECT MIN(ID), MIN(Type), MIN(Version), (Type + Version) FROM TableName Group By (Type + Version)`

Comment: or just do it properly at first :P

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for.
However, I'm going to assume you want one ID for each Type and Version.
If that is what you want use: min(id) or max(id) in the select list and do not add anything to the group by

```
select min(id) as min_id, type, version from tablename group by type,version
```

or

```
select max(id) as max_id, type, version from tablename group by type,version
```

Comment: It's the `min(id)`. If it was the `max(id)`, it would select ids 1,2,4 and 5. Another thing, SQL Server might be case insensitive but try to put the columns like they are in the table (and question).

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple, just do this:

```
select min(ID), Type, Version
from tablename
order by ID
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work (if I've understood correctly):

```
declare @table table (ID int, theType varchar(5), theVersion varchar(5))

INSERT INTO @table (ID, theType, theVersion)
VALUES 
(1, 'A', '200'),
(2, 'A', '100'),
(3, 'B', '200'),
(4, 'B', '200'),
(5, 'B', '100')

SELECT a1.ID, a1.theType, a1.theVersion
FROM @table a1
LEFT JOIN @table a2 ON a2.theType = a1.theType AND a2.theVersion = a1.theVersion AND a2.ID < a1.ID
WHERE a2.ID IS NULL
```